# Why "Do not use `expect` in hooks such as `before`"?

Tags: rspec, rubocop-rspec

My question is pretty much explained by the title. I was trying to google it but did not find anything satisfying at all. rubocop-rspec [does not allow `expect` inside `before`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop-rspec/RuboCop/Cop/RSpec/ExpectInHook), why is that? Is there a good reason to avoid such a usage? Thanks for your explanations in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Four phase test](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/four-phase-test) is a testing pattern commonly used for unit tests. It's general form:

```
test do
  setup
  exercise
  verify
  teardown
end
```

`before` is part of the `setup` phase where the developer creates the scenario and supporting data.

`expect` is part of the `verify` phase, which happens inside a `it` block.

A common pattern is to use `allow` in `before` blocks and use `expect` in `it` blocks for example.

```rb
RSpec.describe User do
  describe '#forgot_password' do
    before { allow(EmailService).to receive(:send) }

    subject { FactoryBot.create(:user).forgot_password }

    it 'sends an email to user to start the password resetting process' do
      subject
      expect(EmailService).to have_received(:send).with(...)
    end
  end
end
```

`before` blocks can also be added in other layers of the application (`spec_helper.rb`, shared examples) and one does not want to rely on the correct order of before blocks in order for a test to be successful.

Answer (score 2):

Only tests should include expectations (also known as assertions). `before` blocks are meant to configure the environment in which your tests run. They are not meant to be tests themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with expects in `before` filters since you are not changing anything in the examples, you are always testing the general setup, but in `after` filters I do not see a reason to avoid expectations.

When writing tests, context is what matters most, you are testing the same code under different parameters (or contexts), hence, the examples need only to modify the context and the assertion could remain constant.

See this example:

```rb
 RSpec.describe Foo do
  subject { create(:foo) }

  describe 'some_method' do
    let(:foo) { create(:foo) }

    after do
      foo.update_rate
      subject.update_rate

      expect(foo.rate).to be > subject.rate
    end

    it 'gives higher rates to foos with more reviews if all are positive' do
      foo.update!(votes_up_count: 10, reviews_count: 10)
      subject.update!(votes_up_count: 1, reviews_count: 1)
    end

    it 'gives higher rates to foos with less positive reviews and no negative reviews' do
      foo.update!(votes_up_count: 4, reviews_count: 4)
      subject.update!(votes_up_count: 5, reviews_count: 6)
    end
  end
end
```

As opposed to

```rb
 RSpec.describe Foo do
  subject { create(:foo) }

  describe 'some_method' do
    let(:foo) { create(:foo) }

    it 'gives higher rates to foos with more reviews if all are positive' do
      foo.update!(votes_up_count: 10, reviews_count: 10)
      subject.update!(votes_up_count: 1, reviews_count: 1)

      foo.update_rate
      subject.update_rate

      expect(foo.rate).to be > subject.rate
    end

    it 'gives higher rates to foos with less positive reviews and no negative reviews' do
      foo.update!(votes_up_count: 4, reviews_count: 4)
      subject.update!(votes_up_count: 5, reviews_count: 6)

      foo.update_rate
      subject.update_rate

      expect(foo.rate).to be > subject.rate
    end
  end
end
```

So I would not take this cop as gospel to be honest, i think it goes against good testing practices.

Comment: I have to agree with you. The added benefits of DRYing up the tests make sense to me.